# IE 11 - focus moves to different area on different computers after page loads

Tags: jaws-screen-reader, section508

So there are 3 of us. We all have JAWS 2018

I have IE 11 11.557.17763.0 and my two coworkers have IE 11.885.17134.0

So I on the web page in question, there is a drop down menu with a checkbox immediately in the tab order after that. I can drop down that menu, make a choice, the page will load and my focus will move to that checkbox

But my two coworkers, when the page loads for them, focus moved to the URL bar of the IE 11 web browser.

We think that because I am still using an older version of IE, there must have been some kind of IE update that is causing their browsers to perform that action, but I cannot duplicate it on my computer.

Comment: Why are you using IE 11?

Comment: How are you applying the focus to the checkbox? I've had similar issues with old IE 11